# Test Runner class takes long time to build each time a code change is made

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber

Test Runner class takes more than 5 minutes to build and launch each time I change some code in my Maven project with a Cucumber framework.
Could I be pointed to what may cause this problem and what would be the solution to this?

Loading Image :

[image: Loading image]

Comment: Did u get any solution for this? I too face this. Cucumber takes more time to build whenever I make changes and save.

Answer (score 0):

***I would like to guide you on few things related to cucumber speed and leave one thing which may speed up build and execution time initially.***

- ***Configuring the eclipse.ini*** - Go to your Eclipse setup folder & open
  eclipse.ini and update these 2 parameters as -Xms256m & -Xmx2048m (more memory) The Xmx argument is the
  amount of memory Eclipse will get (in simple terms). With -Xmx384m,
  it gets 384 MB of RAM, with -Xmx4G it gets 4 GB, etc.
- In most projects I know, Cucumber test suite speed is not an issue. Of course, running 400 features takes its time, but still each test for itself is reasonably fast. There is nothing you can do to fundamentally speed up such a test (of course, you should be using parallel tests execution).
- ***Cleaning up history and indexes reduce the load on RAM***, and overall HDD usage as well. This result in very high impact on performance. To remove the indexes and history folders, please cleanup all files/folders inside these two folders:

  **For cleaning up indexes** - {workspace path}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core

  **For cleaning up history** - {workspace path}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.history

  Here {workspace path} is the path of eclipse workspace where you create all projects.
- Performance Factor While Opening Feature File - It does seem though that the opening time is proportional to the number of step definition files in the project (or the package defined for where the plugin should look for steps definitions).